# Two dependent random variables with standard normal distribution and zero covariance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I need to find two dependent random variables with standard normal distribution, but with zero covariance. It is easy too find just two dependent random variables with such a distribution (`X` and `-X`, for example), but how I can reach zero covariance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answer by [Google](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent).

Comment: [This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) has also some example distributions which are dependent but have zero correlation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=X$ when $|X|\lt k$ and $Y=-X$ when $|X|\ge k$ for some non-negative $k$.

Then $X$ and $Y$ have standard normal distributions and $cov(X,Y)$ is a continuous  increasing function of $k$, negative when $k$ is close to $0$ and positive when $k$ is large.  So for some $k$ you will have $cov(X,Y)=0$

Comment: Some experimentation suggests $k$ should be slightly more than $1.53817$

Comment: and to be more precise, $k$ is the square root of the median of a chi-squared distribution with $3$ degrees of freedom, which using R code `sqrt(qchisq(0.5,3))` gives about $1.538172$

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ and $Z$ be independent standard normal random variables, and take $Y=Z$ on $\{X\cdot Z\ge 0\}$ and $Y=-Z$ on $\{X\cdot Z <0\}$.

Comment: It might help if you said that you were comparing the normal random variables $Y$ and $Z$, which have zero covariance despite $|Y|=|Z|$ with probability $1$.

Answer (score -1):

Although I haven't worked through all aspects that must be checked, I believe that if you specify

$$[X \mid Y] = Y$$

i.e. that $X$ *becomes* $Y$ when conditioning on $Y$, you obtain

$$\text {Cov}(X,Y) = E(XY) = E[E(XY\mid Y)] = E[YE(X\mid Y)]= E[YE(Y)] =0$$

Note that
$$E(X) = E[E(X\mid Y)] = E[Y] = 0$$

and by the decomposition-of-variance formula

$$\text {Var}(X) = \text {Var}(E[X\mid Y]) + E[\text {Var}(X\mid Y)]=  \text {Var}(E[Y])+E[\text {Var}(Y)] = 0 + 1 = 1$$

i.e. this conditional specification is consistent with the unconditional moments.

So these variables are uncorrelated but not independent.

Comment: What is the meaning of $[X \mid Y = Y]$?

Comment: @Did The verbal description compensates for the confusing notation, which I just attempted to improve (and which still remains a shorthand, but a widespread one)

Comment: Sorry but the notation $[X|Y=Y]$ is NOT widespread, and for good reasons. For your interest, the only reasonable interpretation of the thing I can think of does not lead to covariance zero either.